# MySQL Query with latest date found

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL Query to count the number of computer problems based on severity and date (latest date found for a client)

My Table:

```
CLIENT  DATESCANNED             RISK
user1   2019-02-16              High
user1   2019-02-16              High
user1   2019-02-16              High
user1   2019-03-01              Critical
user1   2019-03-01              Critical

SELECT COUNT(*) as count, `datescanned` FROM table1 WHERE `Risk` = 'Critical' 
and client = 'user1' GROUP BY `Risk`,`DATESCANNED` ORDER BY `DATESCANNED` 
DESC LIMIT 1")
```

Latest Results - I'm interested only in the latest date (2019-03-01) and count of each severity levels (Critical, High, Medium, etc)

The above query works well to find out the number of vulnerability "Critical" which will have a count value of "2" (latest date 2019-03-01)

However, If I use Risk = "High", I want the value to be "0" since the latest date is 2019-03-01 and there is NO "High" for that date.

Now the query for the count of "High" is "3"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Nathalie

Comment: Once you've established your PRIMARY KEY, you can use a JOIN

Answer (score 0):

You would want to change your `ORDER BY`. This query will help you get whatever result you need (just add to the `WHERE` where you would like to narrow your query results).

```
SELECT 
  client,
  datescanned, 
  COUNT(*), 
  risk
FROM 
  test 
GROUP BY 
  client,
  datescanned,
  risk;
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thx Miroslav but there should be something to get the latest date only in the query... something like (datescanned IN (select max(datescanned)) ...